# Why using if-else doesn't save data if first condition is not true with Hibernate and Java?

Tags: java, hibernate

`if-else` perform only first condition well, if first condition is not true then data is not saving.

I'm not using `XML` mapping.

```
public class MyGST {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Model model = new Model();

    InwardGst inwardGst = model.byGSTId(1);

    Double IGST = inwardGst.getIgst();
    Double CGST = inwardGst.getCgst();
    Double SGST = inwardGst.getSgst();
    Double UTGST = inwardGst.getUtgst();

    OutwardGst outwardGst = new OutwardGst();

    if (IGST != null) {
        Double halfTax = IGST / 100 * 50;
        outwardGst.setCgst(halfTax);
        outwardGst.setSgst(halfTax);
    } else {
        outwardGst.setCgst(CGST);
        outwardGst.setSgst(SGST);
        outwardGst.setUtgst(UTGST);
    }
    outwardGst.setName(inwardGst.getName());
    model.saveOutWard(outwardGst);
   }
}
```

Why data couldn't be saved?
Why 'else' part is not executing.

Comment: We have no way to tell from what you've presented.  To sort this out, we'll need a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever.  The size of your project has nothing to do with an MCVE or whether you can present one.  It sounds like you could benefit from following my handy hyperlink to information about what a MCVE *is*, and how to prepare one.  Hint: it is almost never the full source of your project.

Comment: Can you specify "coulnd't be saved" more precisely? Exception, what kind, which error message? Did you check the database, at what point in time, what did you expect? Did you check statements sent to the database? And so on.

Comment: The Model class is suspicious. Does it create a new session / transaction with each call? If so, you would break some of the important Hibernate features (and break transaction isolation by the way).

Comment: debug the code, step through "else" block, check the values CGST,SGST. probably those values also null, but in the entity those properties might be not null or mapped to not null columns.

Comment: The model class looks suspicious because in the way you are calling it, it is hardly possible that you are using Hibernate correctly.

Comment: Check your fields, setters and getters. You probably store the value in a `double` instead of a `Double`. Also check the default constructor whether it applies default values. Even the database could apply a default value.

Comment: @SwapnilNagtilak: Most probably, yes. If there is a `double`, it cannot be null.

Answer (score 0):

Check your fields, setters and getters. You probably store the value in a double instead of a Double. Also check the default constructor whether it applies default values. Even the database could apply a default value.

Comment: double is generated by POJO I tried make it Double but that being cause error.

Comment: I think this code   if (IGST != null) { is ambiguous. Cause this always returning true.  In database field is not nullable.

Comment: I make fields nullable but problem is still persist.

Answer (score -1):

1. Setup show sql true on your hibernate configuration.

   > You will see the insert command
2. Check your entity if you have configured @Column mapping correctly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.  It would be more appropriate as a comment on the question, and once you've gained a little more rep, you'll be able to make such comments.